# Fixed date without maketitle

Tags: datetime

```
begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
    \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}

        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{logo}\\[0.9cm]

        {\huge title...... \\}
        \vspace{1.5cm}

        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushleft} \large
        Author: \\[5pt]
        {\Large\bfseries me.......}\\[5pt]
        my-mail........\\[14pt]
        \end{flushleft}
        \end{minipage}
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright} \large
        Supervisor: \\[5pt]
        {\Large\bfseries someone......}\\[5pt]
        thier-email\\[14pt]
        \end{flushright}
        \end{minipage}
        \vspace{1cm}

        {\Large degree from ... : } \\[9pt]

        \textsc{\Large{University....}}\\[1pt]
        \textsc{\Large{{Department.....}}} \\[5pt]
        \vspace{1cm}

        {\large \today}\\[4cm] % Date

    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

So all I want is to use a custom date. A fixed one but not the todays one.
How can I achieve this, since I don't make use of `\maketitle`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried replacing `{\large \today}` with `{\large 1 January 3001}`, say?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to trick `\today` to be set use a fixed date with `\SetDate[01/01/2016]` for example (square brackets dd/mm/yyyy) form with the `advdate` package (old, but still working!)

If `\SetDate` is used inside the `titlepage` environment, `\today` will show the fixed date only there.

**Note** I do not address other issues of this 'titlepage' here!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{advdate}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{center}

    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{logo}\\[0.9cm]
    \SetDate[01/01/2016]

    {\huge title...... \\}
    \vspace{1.5cm}

    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft} \large
    Author: \\[5pt]
    {\Large\bfseries me.......}\\[5pt]
    my-mail........\\[14pt]
    \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright} \large
    Supervisor: \\[5pt]
    {\Large\bfseries someone......}\\[5pt]
    thier-email\\[14pt]
    \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{1cm}

    {\Large degree from ... : } \\[9pt]

    \textsc{\Large{University....}}\\[1pt]
    \textsc{\Large{{Department.....}}} \\[5pt]
    \vspace{1cm}

    {\large \today}\\[4cm] % Date

      \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would there be a benefit in using `\SetDate` over just hardcoding the date, as Mico proposed?

Comment: @cauchy42: Not really. It's alternative. It's hardcoded the some way (unless in a group)